# How can I specify max_results parameter if I am using Python script for Google Product Search API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision-api, google-product-search

While searching a product_set using command line, we can set a parameter [features.max Results](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching#vision_product_search_get_similar_products-drest) to limit the number of items returned in the response.

```
Field-specific considerations:

features.maxResults - The maximum number of results to be returned.
```

But how can I pass this parameter while running the python script provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/searching#vision_product_search_get_similar_products-python)?

Also, does this parameter affect the response time?

Comment: have you tried to define the parameter in `max_results` inside `ProductSearchParams` ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva No. Could you share the link to the documentation or GitHub?

Comment: The `max_results` is a `feature` parameter. As I could understand from the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-vision/) (also checking the functions signatures) the following should work:
`#add this line for the create feture:#
    feature = vision.Feature(max_results = 4)
    # change the response for this:#
    response = image_annotator_client.product_search(image, image_context=image_context, features = [feature])`

tell me if it works so I can post the final answer.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva Getting the error:
```
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/decorators.py", line 111, in inner
    request = dict(image=image, features=[copied_features], **kwargs)
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'features'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is really not very well written, but I found that you just have to add the parameter `max_results=<max>` inside the method `product_search` as following:

```
response = image_annotator_client.product_search(
        image, image_context=image_context,max_results=2)
```

To confirm that it works, I've added the an debug line inside the file on the google library `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/decorators.py`

And when I run the code, I get the printout of the request made to the api, and as you can see, the parameter is correctly defined:

```
# python3 search.py
```

Result:

```
#BEGIN DEBUG:
{'image': source {
  image_uri: "gs://<bucket>/short-blue.jpeg"
}
, 'features': [{'type_': <Type.PRODUCT_SEARCH: 12>, 'max_results': 2}], 'image_context': product_search_params {
  product_set: "projects/<project>/locations/us-west1/productSets/product-set-name"
  product_categories: "apparel-v2"
  filter: "color:blue"
}
}
#END DEBUG:

Product set index time: 
None
Search results:
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @ewertonvsilva. Although this question is for python, could you help fo GoLang too on where to specify this parameter maxResults?